# Microsoft IIS: how can I change file permissions?

Tags: iis, permissions, file-permissions, folder-permissions

how can I change file/folders permissions on Microsoft IIS ?

Should I use icacls ? Can I use it from ftp ? I'm currently logged in with Microsoft ftp protocol but I get:

```
ftp> icacls
?Invalid command.
```

What's the equivalent of

```
ls -l (to see the permissions)
```

and

```
chmod -R folder +arwx
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These cacls/icacls commands are not available via FTP;  perhaps you can create your own server side script that does the trick.

If you are looking for one time configuration solution, the question may not be programming related

Comment: I actually only have ftp access or I can install php scripts on the server doing that for me. Is possible in this way, or I do need more privilegies ?